# Is the linear regression of two cosine with different phase $\cos(θ_2-θ_1)$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, linear-regression

I noticed the following equality that I verified numerically with Excel to be correct.

The linear regression of two cosine with same frequency but different phase yields the cosine of the phase difference.

$$\frac{\operatorname{COV}(\cos(ωt+\theta_1),\cos(ωt+\theta_2))}{\operatorname{VAR}(\cos(ωt+\theta_1))} = \cos(\theta_2-\theta_1)$$

The following equality is also expected to be correct.

$$\frac{\operatorname{COV}(\cos(ωt+\theta_1),\sin(ωt+\theta_2))}{\operatorname{VAR}(\cos(ωt+\theta_1))} = \sin(\theta_2-\theta_1)$$

How can we prove (or disprove) these equality formally ?

Comment: Which of variables are random?

Comment: t is the random variable. all other parameters are constant.  But I tested by computing all values over the range 0 to 2Pi since it models a physic phenomenon evolving with time and t is time.

Comment: How do you define the Cov and Var for the given functions?

Comment: Cov is the covariance and var is the variance. This is the linear regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using excel functions you are evaluating these values as follows

$$\small \operatorname{COV}(\cos(wt+\theta_1),\cos(wt+\theta_2))=\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}\omega} \cos(wt+\theta_1)\cos(wt+\theta_2)\;dt=\frac\pi{\omega}\cos (\theta_2-\theta_1) \tag 1$$

$$\small \operatorname{COV}(\cos(wt+\theta_1),\sin(wt+\theta_2))=\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}\omega} \cos(wt+\theta_1)\sin(wt+\theta_2)\;dt= \frac\pi{\omega}\sin (\theta_2-\theta_1)\tag 2 $$

$$\small\operatorname{VAR}(\cos(wt+\theta_1))=\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}\omega} \cos^2(wt+\theta_1)\; dt=\frac \pi \omega \tag 3$$

from which the result follows.

---

**Calculation od integrals involved**

For **(1)** we can use that, by "[Product-to-sum identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_identities)"

$$\cos(wt+\theta_1)\cos(wt+\theta_2)=\frac12 \left(\cos(\theta_2-\theta_1)+\cos(2wt+\theta_1+\theta_2)\right)$$

therefore

$$\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}\omega} \cos(wt+\theta_1)\cos(wt+\theta_2)\;dt=$$

$$\require{cancel}=\frac12\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}\omega} \cos(\theta_2-\theta_1)\;dt+\frac12\cancel{\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}\omega} \cos(2wt+\theta_1+\theta_2)\;dt}=\frac12 \frac{2\pi}\omega\cos(\theta_2-\theta_1)$$

Similarly for **(2)** we can use that

$$\cos(wt+\theta_1)\sin(wt+\theta_2)=\frac12 \left(\sin(\theta_2-\theta_1)+\sin(2wt+\theta_1+\theta_2)\right)$$

For **(3)** we can use that

$$\cos^2(wt+\theta_1)= \frac12 \left(1+\cos\left(2wt+2\theta_1\right)\right)$$

therefore

$$\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}\omega} \cos^2(wt+\theta_1)\; dt=\frac12 \int_0^{\frac{2\pi}\omega}1\; dt+\frac12 \cancel{\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}\omega} \cos\left(2wt+2\theta_1\right)\; dt}=\frac \pi \omega$$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Comment: Will the result be the same if we integrate between -∞ and +∞ ?

Comment: @chmike Yes in the limit we have the same ratio by periodicity.